# Display parent value from a self-join table in SSAS

Tags: ssas

```
+------------+------------------+----------+
| EmployeeID | ParentEmployeeID |   Name   |
+------------+------------------+----------+
|          1 |                3 | John Doe |
|          2 |                3 | Jack Doe |
|          3 |                7 | Jane Doe |
+------------+------------------+----------+
```

I have the above table and in SSAS Data View where the ParentEmployeeID has a self-join to the EmployeeID column. I want to create a hierarchy for my Dimension where I can show the Manager > Employee, in terms of the above data I want my report to show the following data:

```
+------------+------------------+
| Manager    | Employee         |
+------------+------------------+
|   Jane Doe |         John Doe |
|   Jane Doe |         Jack Doe |
+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Can you tell us the version of SSAS and what mode (tabular/multi-dimensional)?

Comment: @mmarie SSAS 2017 and multidimensional